# Mimic elastic search index and queries on Java Lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Hello I was using elastic search, but I would like to migrate to Java Lucene.

What I need is to recreate the index in the same way and to recreate the queries in the same way. I though I did it, but the scores I receive from the queries are not quite the same. The results are quite similar, but the score of the result itself is different. Maybe I am missing something. I cannot find enough info and default elastic settings are their equivalents in Lucene.

**I have checked that my Lucene version is the same as on the elastic search that I used**

I will show you my configurations in elastic and how I am reproducing it on Lucene.

This is my elastic search connector for creating the index:

```
"analysis": {
   "analyzer": {
            "default": {           
               "tokenizer": "standard",           
                "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
             }
    }     
}
```

Those are my queries:

Query1)

```
 "query": {
      "dis_max": {
           "queries": [
                { "match": { "field1": "${term}" }}
           ],
      "tie_breaker": 1
     }
 }
```

Query 2)

```
 "query": {
      "dis_max": {
           "queries": [
                { "match": { "field1": "${term}" }},
                { "match": { "field2": "${term}" }},
                { "match": { "field2":  "${term}" }}
           ],
           "tie_breaker": 1
      }
 }
```

**Below is Scala code:**

Those are my `field1, field2 and field3` options when creating the Lucene index:

```
 val CustomStringFieldType: FieldType = {
     val fieldType = new FieldType()
     fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true)
     fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true)
     fieldType.setOmitNorms(false)
     fieldType.setTokenized(true)
     fieldType.setStored(false)
     fieldType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS)
     fieldType.freeze()
     fieldType
   }
```

I use `doc.add(new Field("field1", field1Value, CustomStringFieldType))` to add the fields to a document.

Those are my queries. I am creating the tokens using Standard Analyzer and I am using BM25 similarity algorithm:

```
  def query1(tokens: Seq[String]): Query = {

     var booleanQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder()

     for (token <- tokens) {
       booleanQueryBuilder = booleanQueryBuilder.add(
         new TermQuery(new Term("field1", token)),
         BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
     }
     booleanQueryBuilder.build()
   }

 def query2(tokens: Seq[String]): Query = {

     val queries = new java.util.ArrayList[Query]()

     for (field <- ("field1", "field2", "field3") {

       var booleanQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder()

       for (token <- tokens) {
         booleanQueryBuilder = booleanQueryBuilder.add(
           new TermQuery(new Term(field, token)),
           BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
       }

       val booleanQuery: BooleanQuery = booleanQueryBuilder.build()
       queries.add(booleanQuery)
     }
     new DisjunctionMaxQuery(queries, broadQueryTieBreaker)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The clear difference is your mappings settings.

While you’re selected to have the following in Lucene

```
fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true)
fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true)
fieldType.setOmitNorms(false)
fieldType.setTokenized(true)
fieldType.setStored(false)
fieldType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS)
```

By default, in Elasticsearch:

`term_vector` - disabled by default, so you need to have

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type":        "text",
          "term_vector": "with_positions"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To store positions like you’re doing in Lucene.

So, since you’re migrating to Lucene you need to disable term vectors, like they were in your Elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks a lot for noting this. Unfortunately this didn't change the score significantly.